# Open a blob in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, blob

I'm working with croppie js and the lib returns a blob object.

But for my website I have two options, use the blob for the Microsoft's OCR (which works perfectly) to have the text in the part of the image or have the part itself and so I need to open the blob to get the URL to put it in the src's field of an image element

I found this on https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Blob

```
function write_img(blob)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
        // reader.result contient le contenu du
        // blob sous la forme d'un tableau typé
        });
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + reader.result + "\" >";
}
```

But it returns null, Is anyone able to help?

Comment: thanks a lot it work ! I didn't know readAsDataUrl was asynchronous and I don't know a lot about call backbut thank ! :)

Comment: see answer below - see my comment regarding which event you really should be listening for :p

Comment: yes thank I'm working on it :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it return null, any help ?

It returns `null` because `loadend` event is not fired yet.

This line

```
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + reader.result + "\" >";
```

needs to be inside the `loadend` event handler

```
function write_img(blob)
{
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + reader.result + "\" >";
     });
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

Comment: preferably listen for `load` not `loadend` - as `loadend` is fired for both success and failure

Answer (score 1):

Use the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) if you want to display images... avoid base64 since it takes up more memory & time to encode/decode base64

Object url will load faster and is also synchronous

```
function write_img(blob) {
  var img = new Image()

  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('result').appendChild(img)
    // revoke the url when it's not needed anymore.
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
  }

  img.onerror = function() {
    // not an image.
  }
}
```